# Is this a valid instance of "extending by continuity" in defining diagonal operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

In a functional analysis textbook I've encountered the following paragraph:

> "Suppose that $H$ is a hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$.
>   Choose any bounded sequence of numbers $\{a_n\}$ and set
>   $Ae_n=a_ne_n$. Extend $A$ by linearity to any finite linear
>   combination of $e_n$, and **extend $A$ to all of $H$ by continuity**."

I know how to make sense of a (bounded) diagonal operator on a Hilbert space, so that's not what my question is about.

As far as I can say, the expression 'extending a function $f$ by continuity' is applicable when $f$ is known to be continuous on a dense subset $S$ of $X$ and we want to define a continuous function on $X$ whose restriction to $S$ is $f$ and continuity of $f$ on $S$ guarantees that this is indeed doable in a unique way.

However, in this context of the diagonal operator, I'm not sure if the usage of the phrase "extending by continuity" is justified.  Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the linear subspace of $\mathcal H$ given by $\text{Span}\{e_1, e_2, \cdots \}$. Then $S$ is a dense subspace of $\mathcal H$. Now $A$ is defined only on $S$, but since for all $v\in S$, write $v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_ie_i$,

$$\begin{split} \|Av\|^2 &= \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n Av_i e_i\right\| ^2= \left\| \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i e_i\right\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2\cdot | v_i |^2 \\
&\le M \sum_{i=1}^n | v_i |^2 = M\|v\|^2.
\end{split} $$

Where $M$ is the bound for $|a_i|^2$ and we use the fact that $\|v\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^2$. Thus $A : S\to S$ is continuous and can be uniquely extended to $\mathcal H$.

Comment: I believe you need $|a_i|^2$ and $M$ should be an upper bound for the set $\{|a_i|^2\}$. But my question is what is the advantage of defining $A$ on $S$ first and not doing it on $H$ directly in this context?

Comment: Yes, it should be $|a_i|^2$ (edited). I am answering that "the usage of extending continuity" is justified" by explicitly writing down that dense set $S$. @EPS